# How do I use ssh-agent as a wrapper program?

Tags: environment-variables, ssh-agent, awesome, lightdm, startx

I'm trying to start `awesome` windows manager as a subprocess of `ssh-agent`. It worked when I used `startx` (`ssh-agent startx`). But now I'm trying to make it work under `lightdm`.

`lightdm` starts `/usr/bin/xinitrcsession-helper`:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec $HOME/.xinitrc
```

`~/.xinitrc`:

```
ssh-agent awesome
```

And what I get is:

```
  509     1   lightdm         /usr/bin/lightdm
  526   509     Xorg            /usr/lib/Xorg :0 -seat seat0 -auth /run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
  877   509     lightdm         lightdm --session-child 14 21
 1003   877       xinitrcse       /bin/bash /usr/bin/xinitrcsession-helper
 1028  1003         awesome         awesome
 1029  1028           ssh-a           ssh-agent awesome
```

And `set | grep SSH` returns nothing.

Then I start another `xterm` (`ssh-agent xterm`) and it works:

```
 1636     1   xterm           xterm
 1638  1636     bash            bash
 1651  1638       vim             vim
 9435  1651         xterm           xterm
 9447  9435           ssh-a           ssh-agent xterm
 9449  9435           bash            bash
10464  9449             ps              ps -eHo pid,ppid,comm,args
10465  9449             les             less
```

The strange thing here is that `ssh-agent` is a child of a program it starts. Can you explain that?

And how do I run `awesome` so that the programs I start after that could see `ssh-agent`?

**UPD** Regarding `ssh-agent` being a child to the command it runs. That is made to be able to replace `command` with [`ssh-agent command`](https://marc.info/?l=openssh-unix-dev&m=130495725421254&w=4). So, `ssh-agent` forks, and parent `exec`s the `command`.

**UPD** My bad, I was using `xbindkeys` to start `xterm`, and the former happened to be started before `ssh-agent`. Like in, `xbindkeys && ssh-agent awesome`. So, it didn't have `SSH_*` variables to pass to `xterm`. Or so is my most probable explanation. When using `awesome`'s builtin facilities to start `xterm`, environment variables are passed down all right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your update you mentioned that you start `xterm` from `xbindkeys` and since you run

```
xbindkeys && ssh-agent awesome
```

`bindkeys` will not have the SSH-related environment, and as a consequence of that, `xterm` won't either.

To solve this, I would suggest

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
xbindkeys && awesome
```

Now, this would set the variables for both `xbindkeys` and `awesome` (which may well be what you need and want), but it would not automatically kill the `ssh-agent` process when you log out.

For that, you could use (with `bash`),

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
trap 'eval "$(ssh-agent -k)"' EXIT
xbindkeys && awesome
```

or something similar.  This would call `ssh-agent -k` which would kill the agent, as soon as that shell exited or was terminated by `TERM`, `HUP` or `INT`.

Running `eval` on the output of `ssh-agent -k` would just unset the SSH-variables, and it may not be needed (since the script is about to exit anyway), so the trap may be set up to run just `ssh-agent -k >/dev/null` instead.

---

The thing about `ssh-agent` being a child process of the command that it starts just *looks* strange.

`ssh-agent` forks off the actual agent process, and then replaces the original process with that of the command it's supposed to run (using `exec()`).  The result is that the original process (`xterm` in your second process tree) is the parent of the agent:

```
/*
 * Fork, and have the parent execute the command, if any, or present
 * the socket data.  The child continues as the authentication agent.
 */
if (D_flag || d_flag) {
        log_init(__progname,
            d_flag ? SYSLOG_LEVEL_DEBUG3 : SYSLOG_LEVEL_INFO,
            SYSLOG_FACILITY_AUTH, 1);
        format = c_flag ? "setenv %s %s;\n" : "%s=%s; export %s;\n";
        printf(format, SSH_AUTHSOCKET_ENV_NAME, socket_name,
            SSH_AUTHSOCKET_ENV_NAME);
        printf("echo Agent pid %ld;\n", (long)parent_pid);
        fflush(stdout);
        goto skip;
}
pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        cleanup_exit(1);
}
if (pid != 0) {         /* Parent - execute the given command. */
        close(sock);
        snprintf(pidstrbuf, sizeof pidstrbuf, "%ld", (long)pid);
        if (ac == 0) {
                format = c_flag ? "setenv %s %s;\n" : "%s=%s; export %s;\n";
                printf(format, SSH_AUTHSOCKET_ENV_NAME, socket_name,
                    SSH_AUTHSOCKET_ENV_NAME);
                printf(format, SSH_AGENTPID_ENV_NAME, pidstrbuf,
                    SSH_AGENTPID_ENV_NAME);
                printf("echo Agent pid %ld;\n", (long)pid);
                exit(0);
        }
        if (setenv(SSH_AUTHSOCKET_ENV_NAME, socket_name, 1) == -1 ||
            setenv(SSH_AGENTPID_ENV_NAME, pidstrbuf, 1) == -1) {
                perror("setenv");
                exit(1);
        }
        execvp(av[0], av);
        perror(av[0]);
        exit(1);
}
```

(the child process then continues executing the rest of the code)

This allows you to kill the agent without much consequence to the command that you'd want to run, for example.

Comment: Actually, I've found answers to all my questions. But you've got not a bad answer there. Although I've got my 2 cents to share. I'd still prefer the wrapper solution. Where you put `xbindkeys && exec awesome` into `awesome.sh`, and then `ssh-agent awesome.sh`. And no need for all the trickery with traps, and everything. Regarding traps, from my experience with recent releases of `bash`, `EXIT` is enough.

Comment: ...As for `ssh-agent` ending up being a child, it's unexpected no matter how you look at it. The docs says that `ssh-agent` executes the command if given. And the most straightforward way is to run it as a subprecess. Also, I've failed to state it clearly, and I've got no authoritative proof link, but most likely the reason for `ssh-agent` making itself running as a subprocess is to be able to transparently replace `command` with [`ssh-agent command`](https://marc.info/?l=openssh-unix-dev&m=130496193226557&w=4).

Comment: @x-yuri I missed the fact that you were using `bash`. Other shells may not execute the `EXIT` trap when terminating due to a signal.  I've also added the actual forking code from `ssh-agent`.